# what does ', '.join(genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3]) precisely do?

Tags: python, django, loops

Hi I'am lerning Django web framework and I came acros this line of code:

```
return ', '.join(genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3])
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site#configure_list_views)

I want to know what precisely everything in this line does.
I know that `.join` joins a tuple into the string with `', '` as a separator.

But I have no idea how `genre.name for genre in self.genre` loop works.
What does `.all()` function do and how `[:3]` connects with all of this.

I tried searching what `.all()` does but I only found documentation for `all(parameter)`.
I tried searching what `a for b in c` loop does but I only found documentation `for a in b`.
I know that `[:3]` return 3 values but I don't know how this connects with the rest of the code.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects

Answer (score 0):

genre is a django model many-to-many field to another model and you can do a query on it like on a model.

so genre.all()[:3] will first give you all related items of genre and then slice the first 3 of them.

so all() here is a method that is part of the django model manager; there you can find it.

Comment: Ok, genre.name is a outside model property, self.genere is a internal model property. But how does `a for b in c` loop works(genre.name for genre in self.genre)?

Comment: (expression for item in iterable) is a python generator. Expression will be returned for each item in iterable. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators